running PowerShell script as win32 app in Intune fails
i built a script which simulate BGinfo functionality but via PowerShell
New-Item -Path "C:\wallpaper" -ItemType Directory -Force
$imageUrl = "https://r4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/410/867/750/vector-forest-sunset-forest-sunset-forest-wallpaper-b3abc35d0d699b056fa6b247589b18a8.jpg"
$backgroundImagePath = "C:\wallpaper\downloaded_image.jpg"
$imagePath = "C:\wallpaper\currentnew.jpg"
 
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $imageUrl -OutFile $backgroundImagePath
 
$computerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$drive = Get-PSDrive -Name C
$totalSize = [math]::round(($drive.Used + $drive.Free) / 1GB, 2)
$freeSpace = [math]::round($drive.Free / 1GB, 2)

$ipAddress = (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias Ethernet).IPAddress

$windowsVersion = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion').ProductName
$buildNumber = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion').CurrentBuild
$releaseId = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion').ReleaseId
 

$latestUpdate = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion').DisplayVersion
 

$lastRestart = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime
 

if (-not ([System.Type]::GetType("Wallpaper"))) {
    $code = @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class Wallpaper {
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);
    public const int SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20;
    public const int SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
    public const int SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;
}
"@
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -PassThru | Out-Null
}
 

$bitmap = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::FromFile($backgroundImagePath)
$graphics = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bitmap)
$font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("calibri", 35)
$brush = [System.Drawing.Brushes]::White
 

$xPos = $bitmap.Width - 990 # Adjust this value as needed to fit the text
$yPos = -180
$lineHeight = 50 # Adjust the line height as needed
 

$yPos += $lineHeight * 10
 
$graphics.DrawString("PC Name: $computerName", $font, $brush, $xPos, $yPos)
$graphics.DrawString("Drive C: Total Size: $totalSize GB, Free Space: $freeSpace GB", $font, $brush, $xPos, $yPos + $lineHeight)
$graphics.DrawString("IP Address: $ipAddress", $font, $brush, $xPos, $yPos + $lineHeight * 2)
$graphics.DrawString("Logged-on User: $loggedUser", $font, $brush, $xPos, $yPos + $lineHeight * 3)
$graphics.DrawString("Windows Version: $windowsVersion", $font, $brush, $xPos, $yPos + $lineHeight * 4)
$graphics.DrawString("Build Number: $buildNumber", $font, $brush, $xPos, $yPos + $lineHeight * 5)
$graphics.DrawString("Latest Update: $latestUpdate", $font, $brush, $xPos, $yPos + $lineHeight * 6)
$graphics.DrawString("Last Restart: $lastRestart", $font, $brush, $xPos, $yPos + $lineHeight * 7)
$graphics.DrawLine([System.Drawing.Pens]::White, $xPos, $yPos + $lineHeight * 8, $xPos + 560, $yPos + $lineHeight * 8) # Add a separator line
$boldFont = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("calibri", 30, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$graphics.DrawString("For any enquiries please send a ticket to ", $boldFont, $brush, $xPos, $yPos + $lineHeight * 9)
$graphics.DrawString("helpdesk@mydomain.com", $boldFont, $brush, $xPos, $yPos + $lineHeight * 10)
$bitmap.Save($imagePath, [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Png)
$graphics.Dispose()
$bitmap.Dispose()


Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\' -Name WallpaperStyle -Value "2"
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\' -Name TileWallpaper -Value "0"


[Wallpaper]::SystemParametersInfo([Wallpaper]::SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, $imagePath, [Wallpaper]::SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE -bor [Wallpaper]::SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE)

When i run this script from the pc it runs well.  while when i run it as win32 app  (with Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass)
Intuner manage to run this script, the image file is downloaded however then it reach the section of fetching and inserting data i fails

Directory: C:\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  ----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        11/28/2024   1:16 PM                wallpaper
Unable to find type [System.Drawing.Bitmap].
At C:\WINDOWS\IMECache\6d9f5b55-70d9-4520-8836-97b18f1b76af_1\CorpWallpeper.ps1:52 char:11

$bitmap = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::FromFile($backgroundImagePath)

      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Drawing.Bitmap:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
Unable to find type [System.Drawing.Graphics].
At C:\WINDOWS\IMECache\6d9f5b55-70d9-4520-8836-97b18f1b76af_1\CorpWallpeper.ps1:53 char:13

$graphics = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bitmap)

        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Drawing.Graphics:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
New-Object : Cannot find type [System.Drawing.Font]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At C:\WINDOWS\IMECache\6d9f5b55-70d9-4520-8836-97b18f1b76af_1\CorpWallpeper.ps1:54 char:9

$font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("calibri", 35)

    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand`

ill appreciate any help
Tried to run it as a script from script section in Intune but it doesnt work at all.

You're missing loading of the System.Drawing assembly in your code. Put Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing on top and it should be solved.
